# Passing Props to component

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-paper

To prevent recreating the same react native paper component and its icon using `@expo/vector-icons` in all my typescript files, I created a reusable component where I just have these react native paper component and the expo icons pass all their (react native paper and expo icons) props as parameter to the component but I was experiencing an error.

**The code:**

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {FAB, Badge} from 'react-native-paper'
import { Ionicons, MaterialIcons, MaterialCommunityIcons, Entypo } from '@expo/vector-icons';

type Props ={
    iconType: string
    iconName: string
    iconSize: number
    badgeLabel: string
    badgeVisibility: boolean
}

export const ThoughtsIcons = (Props: Props) => {
  return <>
    <View>
      <FAB style={ styles.iconStyle } icon= {
      {Props.iconType == "Entypo" &&
      <Entypo name={Props.iconName} size={Props.iconSize} 
      />
      }
      {Props.iconType == "Ionicons" &&
      <Ionicons name={Props.iconName} size={Props.iconSize} 
      />
      }
      {Props.iconType == "MaterialCommunityIcons" &&
      <MaterialCommunityIcons name={Props.iconName} size={Props.iconSize} 
      />
      }
      {Props.iconType == "MaterialIcons" &&
      <MaterialIcons name={Props.iconName} size={Props.iconSize} 
      />
      }
    }
    
      />

<Badge visible={Props.badgeVisibility} style={ styles.badgeStyle}>
{Props.badgeLabel}
</Badge>
    </View>
  </>
}
```

**The error:**

```
1)
{Props.iconType == "Entypo"
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'Props' does not exist in type 'ImageURISource | ImageURISource[] 
| Readonly

2)
<Entypo name={Props.iconName} size={Props.iconSize}
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"direction" | "map" | "key" | "link" | "address" | "code" | "menu" | "video" 
| "circle" | "image" | "mask" | "switch" | "text" | "radio" | "list" 
| "document" | "grid" | "note" |
```